# Javadoc identifying superclass constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

If I go to the Javadoc page for the [RandomGenerator class](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/jtf/javadoc/complete/acm/util/RandomGenerator.html) I see a summary of the class constructor and methods. It says `public class RandomGenerator extends Random`.

How can I find out more information about how `RandomGenator class` invokes the constructor of Random class? I don't see any references in `RandomGenerator class` to it's superclass constructor.

Comment: The Javadoc is about the public contract of the class. How it accomplishes that contract is up to the implementation. Which superclass constructor it calls is its business, not yours, at least as far as the Javadoc's obligations are concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have to contact authors. For some reason they decided not to include this information into javadoc (public contract).

You may also look into class sources or use java decompiler if you don't have sources.

In case class constructor doesn't call `super()` directly that means that superclass has no-argument constructor which call is the first line of your class constructor **always**, and you do not need to call it explicitly.

P. S. My answer has two different approaches. I apologize for that, I just not quite sure whether you have sources for analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, you can't from the javadocs directly.

You can look at the parent class, find that it has 2 constructors, guess which one is being called based on the parameters the child class constructor exposes.

And ofcourse the most conclusive answer can be given by looking at the source code if available or decompiling the class if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

> Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

Therefore, they just decided not to actually write the call to the `super` constructor and use the default one.